# Error while creating Azure IR:Check the linked service configuration is correct

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Error while creating an Azure IR data factory.

> Cannot connect to SQL Database:
> 'mysqlserversowmya.database.windows.net', Database: 'master', User:
> 'adminuser'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and
> make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to
> access.

Comment: Hi Sowmya b, did the error solved now?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have open the SQL database firewall: **add client ip** and **Allow Azure services and resources to access this server** On portal:

[image]

To see: [Server-level IP firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule)

Hope this helps.